# Automatically assign event handler to new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Say I have some code like this which is called on `$(document).ready()`

```
$(".someClass").click(function(){
    //do something 
});
```

Later on I have some jquery to create an element with the class `someClass`. Is there anyway to automatically attach the click from above or do I have to manually attach it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `live`, which also listens for new elements

```
$(".someClass").live('click', function(){
    //do something 
});
```

But, as of jquery 1.7 it has been deprecated. It's advised to use `on` instead.

But in order to use `on`, you need a container for the elements you want to bind a handler. Of course you could use `body` or `document` but it's better to use a more specific element

```
$(".someClassContainer").on('click', '.someClass' function(){
        //do something 
    });
```

Comment: Live is deprecated, you should use `.on()`

Comment: Thank you, only just started on jquery so still learning the ropes. btw it works :) +1

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is possible.

```
$("body").on("click", ".someClass", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use latest version of jquery and `on`

```
$(document).on('click', '.someClass', function(e){
    //do something 
});
```

`Live` is deprecated but you can use it, anyway (not recommended).

```
$('.someClass').live('click', function(e){
    //do something 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two easy ways of doing this, the first is with `on()`:

```
$(".someClassParentElementPresentInTheDOMonDOMReady").on('click','.someClass',
    function(){
        //do something 
    });
```

And the other is to simply assign the click-handler at the point of creation of the new element; I don't know how you're doing that, but an example is below:

```
$('#addElement').click(
    function(){
        var newElem = $('<div />',{'class' : 'someClass'}).click(function(){
            // do something }).appendTo('.someClassParentElementPresentInTheDOMonDOMReady');
```

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).